# Combining 2 SQL queries into one single query

Tags: sql, db2

I need help with a SQL query. I am trying to use 'IN' clause to get results from multiple where conditions.

This is the query:

```
SELECT ID,LOCALCODE,STRING 
FROM SSODEV.TRANSLATION 
WHERE STRINGKEY IN (SELECT DESCRIPTIONKEY 
                    FROM SSODEV.APPFIELD 
                    WHERE APPLICATIONID='a6e60e4d-e9ca-4a48-aa7f-0eb4d40ab260',
                    SELECT DISPLAYNAMEKEY 
                    FROM SSODEV.APPFIELD 
                    WHERE APPLICATIONID='a6e60e4d-e9ca-4a48-aa7f-0eb4d40ab260');
```

However for the above I get an error

> DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=,;8-aa7f-0eb4d40ab260';INTERSECT, DRIVER=4.13.127`

My intention is to get a single query for the below 2 queries

```
select * 
from SSODEV.TRANSLATION 
where stringkey = 'appField.e3c94305-84b4-4190-9040-244429a3c0f0.description'

select * 
from SSODEV.TRANSLATION 
where stringkey = 'appField.e3c94305-84b4-4190-9040-244429a3c0f0.name'
```

"stringkey" for query 1 and query 2 comes from table SSODEV.APPFIELD with column names DISPLAYNAMEKEY and DESCRIPTIONKEY. Hence they have to be fetched as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this query:

```
select *
from SSODEV.TRANSLATION
where stringkey in ('appField.e3c94305-84b4-4190-9040- 
244429a3c0f0.description',
                    'appField.e3c94305-84b4-4190-9040-244429a3c0f0.name'
                   )
```

Comment: Sorry Steve , there is a modification, the problem is "stringkey" values for query 1 and query 2 comes from table SSODEV.APPFIELD with column names DISPLAYNAMEKEY and DESCRIPTIONKEY.

Comment: Then you can try
    
    SELECT ID,LOCALCODE,STRING 
    FROM SSODEV.TRANSLATION 
    WHERE STRINGKEY IN ((SELECT DESCRIPTIONKEY 
                    FROM SSODEV.APPFIELD 
                    WHERE APPLICATIONID in('a6e60e4d-e9ca-4a48-aa7f-0eb4d40ab260','a6e60e4d-e9ca-4a48-aa7f-0eb4d40ab260')));

Comment: or alternativelly you can try to join the second table:



    
    SELECT ID,LOCALCODE,STRING 
    FROM SSODEV.TRANSLATION 
    left join SSSODEV.APPFIELD on SSODEV.APPFIELD.DESCRIPTIONKEY = SSODEV.TRANSLATION.STRINGKEY
    WHERE APPLICATIONID IN ('a6e60e4d-e9ca-4a48-aa7f-0eb4d40ab260','a6e60e4d-e9ca-4a48-aa7f-0eb4d40ab260');

Answer (score 0):

@Suraj following your comment: Then you can try

```
SELECT ID,LOCALCODE,STRING 
FROM SSODEV.TRANSLATION 
WHERE STRINGKEY IN ((SELECT DESCRIPTIONKEY 
                FROM SSODEV.APPFIELD 
                WHERE APPLICATIONID in('a6e60e4d-e9ca-4a48-aa7f-0eb4d40ab260','a6e60e4d-e9ca-4a48-aa7f-0eb4d40ab260')));
```

or alternativelly you can try to join the second table:

```
SELECT ID,LOCALCODE,STRING 
FROM SSODEV.TRANSLATION 
left join SSSODEV.APPFIELD on SSODEV.APPFIELD.DESCRIPTIONKEY = SSODEV.TRANSLATION.STRINGKEY
WHERE APPLICATIONID IN ('a6e60e4d-e9ca-4a48-aa7f-0eb4d40ab260','a6e60e4d-e9ca-4a48-aa7f-0eb4d40ab260');
```